# Access nested JSON data on MediaWiki

Tags: php, json, mediawiki

I am trying to access the contents of a nested JSON from within a MediaWiki wiki. I have already researched the [External Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:External_Data) extension, but it does not support nested JSON objects. It only works with one-dimensional objects, versus potentially nested properties.

Let's assume I want to work with the [Chuck Norris API](http://api.icndb.com), for example. It returns a JSON in this form:

```
{
    "type": "success",
    "value": {
        "id": 334,
        "joke": "John Doe qualified with a top speed of 324 mph at the Daytona 500, without a car.",
        "categories": []
    }
}
```

I want to be able to access the contents of the `value` key in some meaningful form in MediaWiki. This functionality [is not offered by the External Data](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk:External_Data/Archive_2016#Access_to_array_on_JSON) extension, and I was wondering if there was another way that I could do it (another extension, writing custom PHP, writing custom JavaScript).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in php, use:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
//true makes it an associative array
```

Then just access it using normal methods.

```
echo $array['value']['id'];
```